# Saving a large sparse pandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a large sparse pandas dataframe of 477k rows and 530 columns with different dtypes. When I check the memory usage within pandas using:

```
df.memory_usage().sum()
```

It gives me the size in gigabytes. So, I converted the dataframe to a sparse dataframe using:

```
df.to_sparse()
```

And, now the memory_usage is reduced to 80MB. But, when I export it to excel, the size of the file on the disk is around 500MB. The file opens but it takes forever to open and explore the data. When I select a column in excel it should give me the count of the number of records in that column and in this case, it gives me the count as the length of the dataframe(i.e 477k rows) but in reality, that column has around 15000 records filled with data and rest all are blank(same for all the columns). I assume while exporting the data to excel, excel it is filling data in blank cells too. Is there a way I can get rid of this problem?